# define LOCAL_C_INCLUDES in gradle ndk{} DSL?

Tags: android, android-ndk, gradle-experimental

How can i define `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` inside `ndk{}` block of my module gradle??

This ndk block of  my module gradle file:

```
ndk {
            platformVersion = 21;
            moduleName "main"
            toolchain = "clang"
            stl = 'gnustl_static'         
            cppFlags.addAll(['-std=c++11', '-Wall', '-D__STDC_INT64__'])
            ldLibs.addAll(['android', 'log'])     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **CFlags** and **cppFlags** for that:

```
CFLags.add '-Ipath/to/include'
```

and so on.